# Can I add columns to filtered data without it all being mismatched when the original data is reorganized?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, filterfunction

I'm creating a tech inventory spreadsheet in google sheets, and am trying to figure out how to add additional columns to filtered data. The inventory has a main spreadsheet "All Tech Inventory". Some of our tech are loaners, so I have a second sheet that filters out only the loaners, called "Loaner Tech". I made this with the filter function, pulling out all data where the user read "Loaner". My goal is to add columns in the Loaners sheet, so I can track who the loaner went to, on what date, and when we can expect it back.

The problem is that if the data in the "All Tech Inventory" sheet is re-ordered (reorganized by user, department, etc) the data in the "Loaner Laptops" sheet also changes order, but their corresponding loaned to/date loaned/due date columns don't also move. Is there a way to "marry" these three columns to the filtered Loaner data, so that if the filtered data moves the added stuff will also? Or, is there a way to "freeze" the loaner sheet so that new loaners will be added when the "All Tech Inventory" is updated with a new one, but they'll never be reordered no matter what happens on the main sheet?

Hope this is clear, and I'm also open to any other creative ideas that totally change how I'm approaching this! As long as I'm able to see all the tech, see just the loaner tech, and also track who it's being loaned to without that being on the main inventory sheet.

Comment: Typically one needs to distinguish between a "Master file" (record of assets), and a transaction file (record of loans and returns).